# SQL query that brings all records that doesn't includes a join with a given value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Lets suppose we have

```
Owners
id

Dogs
id
owner_id
trained (boolean)
```

I want to get all owners who **don't** have **any** trained dog, including those who **don't have a dog**.

So if one owner has one trained dog, and one dog non trained, that owner should not appear, because already has a trained dog.

I tried with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM owners o 
LEFT JOIN dogs d on d.owner_id = o.id
WHERE
  d.trained = false OR d.trained IS NULL.
```

But this query returns records including owners that have dogs trained, as long as they have a non trained dog.

I wan't to get only:

- Owners who don't have a single trained dog
- Owner who don't have dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not exists` operator does exactly that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   owners o
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FORM   dogs d
                   WHERE  trained = true AND d.owner_id = o.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Owners o,Dogs d
WHERE  o.id=d.owner_id
and  d.trained=false;
```

Comment: The problem with this query is that if the owner has 2 dogs, one trained, and the other not trained, it will filter only the non trained. And the owner will will get incorrectly into the resultset. The idea is that if the owner has ANY trained dog, it should not appear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!